# Type straight quotes (",') when smart quotes is turned on

Tags: text, input-source, text-input

I love smart quotes in macOS, but for those few times where I really need a straight quote (when manually typing  links, for example), I can’t find a quick keyboard shortcut to insist on the straight ones.

Is this possible with a simple keyboard shortcut?

**Update:** The most effective way seems to be creating a custom keyboard shortcut for turning off/on Smart Quotes in individual applications (Edit > Substitutions in supported applications) for those few times I do need a straight quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added `"` and `'` as replacements for something, then the replaced quotes were not converted to smart quotes in a few quick experiments. For example, setting `""` and `''` to be replaced by `"` and `'` respectively:

[image]

Typing `""foo"" ''bar''` resulted in `"foo" 'bar'` with normal quotes. As shortcuts go, just double tapping the button instead of single tapping makes for a convenient shortcut.

Comment: That’s a good way to do it! For some reason, this method does not work for single quotes for me, only for the double ones. I have no idea why. But since I’m mostly only interested in the double quotes, I’m happy :)

Comment: Update: It seems like this method produced straight quotes that breaks in at least one use case. Manually typing a link before posting it on a post on https://dribbble.com removes the link altogether, while turning off Smart Quotes and doing the same thing works just fine. I have no idea as to why this happens. I’ve found a new solution though, see the update in the question.

Comment: This appears to no longer work, at least as of macOS Catalina. It also does not work on iPadOS—if you have smart quotes set, the transformation happens after the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

In some Mac applications e.g. Pages, you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+quote or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+quote (for a double quote).
Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Microsoft Word for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If the software you're using has auto-changed your straight quote to a smart quote, you can also just use the universal <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> 'Undo' keyboard shortcut to change the smart quote back to a straight quote.

Comment: `Command-Z` is “Undo”, whete does it convert quotes?

Comment: @Allan I assume what they mean is that if you've typed a straight quote and the application you're using (e.g. MS Word) changes it to a smart quote, then using the `Command-Z` shortcut will just undo it, and therefore return it to a straight quote. Matt, assuming this is the case, perhaps you could add that to provide some context and improve your answer.

Comment: @Monomeeth, that may be the case, but another user looking to manually change (existing) one quote type to another will be thoroughly confused by this answer.

Comment: @Allan Yes, it really needs some extra context to be useful. I'll keep an eye on it to see if Matt returns to improve their answer. If not I'll edit it to convey what I assume they're trying to say.